# Best way to associate HTML element with array element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a card game, and the way I have it set up currently is that each card is an array of two values, a value `number` and a `string` suit.

```
var deck = {
    cards: makeDeck(),
    shuffle: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            var card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.cards.length));
            var card2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.cards.length));
            var temp = this.cards[card1];

            this.cards[card1] = this.cards[card2];
            this.cards[card2] = temp;
        }
        console.log("Deck Shuffled");
    }
}

function makeDeck() {
    var cards = new Array;
    for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
        cards.push(Card(i, 'spade'), Card(i, 'diamonds'), Card(i, 'clubs'), Card(i, 'hearts'));
    }
    return cards;
}

function renderDeck() {
    deck.cards.forEach(element => {
        var card = document.createElement("span");
        card.classList.add("deck", element[1]);
        card.innerHTML = element[0] + "<br />" + element[1];
        if (element === trumpCard) {
            card.classList.add("trump_card");
        }
        document.body.appendChild(card);
    });
}
```

They are all inside of a `deck` array, and I have a function which will create a `<span>` element for each card. Now when the player interacts with the cards, they're clicking on the `<span>` element, but most of my logic and such is much easier to do by using the array of values and suits. My current solution was just to make new variables in each function for the selected element using `innerHTML`, like this:

```
var value = parseInt(el.innerHTML.substr(0, el.innerHTML.indexOf('<')));
var suit = el.innerHTML.substr(el.innerHTML.indexOf('>') + 1, el.innerHTML.length);
```

This is a big pain to do, and was wondering if there's anyway I can easily associate each `<span>` with its respective array element. I was thinking maybe something with `id`s, but not sure on implementation and if it's the best way to go about it.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for an answer in pure js, but it's worthy to mention that front-end frameworks make this trivial, eg. `deck.map((card, index) => { return (<span key={index}>{card.value} of {card.suit}</span>); });` -- when `deck` changes, so does the DOM.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping for a vanilla solution to this as I'm still new to front-end, but I'll keep this in mind for the future in case I want to redo the game using a framework. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to access the number and suit from the raw DOM elements. I would use HTML data attributes for this:

In your render function:

```
card.dataset.value = element[0];
card.dataset.suit = element[1];
```

Then you can access the values later with `el.dataset.value` and `el.dataset.suit`.

You can also get a `NodeList` of all the elements with a specified value/suit by calling something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-suit='spade']");
```

You can read more about data attributes at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Yeah this seems like a great solution, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need separate arrays in the first place for this. If you create your `span` elements and give each an `id` that represents the specific card it represents and a class joining that `span` to a classification of `card`, for example:

```
<span id="h12" class="card">Queen of Hearts</span>
```

You can then gather up all the "cards" into a collection like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".card");
```

And that collection can be indexed or looped over.

Comment: In my functions I need to for example make certain cards playable based on their attribute. With an `id` instead that seems to complicate it, as I'd have to get the card's value and suit by doing something similar to what I had in my example with using `substr` on the `id`. 

As a specific example, in the game you play cards and your opponent has to defend. How they defend is by playing a card that matches the suit, but has a larger value. I would have a function that would give all matching cards an `onClick` function that lets the player play that card.